# How to concatenate lists without using extra memory?

Tags: c#

How do you concatenate huge lists without doubling memory?

Consider the following snippet:

```
 Console.WriteLine($"Initial memory size: {Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64 /1024 /1024} MB");
 int[] a = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000 * 1024 * 1024 / 4).ToArray();
 int[] b = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000 * 1024 * 1024 / 4).ToArray();
 Console.WriteLine($"Memory size after lists initialization: {Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64 / 1024 / 1024} MB");
 List<int> concat = new List<int>();
 concat.AddRange(a.Skip(500 * 1024 * 1024 / 4));
 concat.AddRange(b.Skip(500 * 1024 * 1024 / 4));
 Console.WriteLine($"Memory size after lists concatenation: {Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64 / 1024 / 1024} MB");
```

The output is:

```
Initial memory size: 12 MB
Memory size after lists initialization: 2014 MB
Memory size after lists concatenation: 4039 MB
```

I would like to keep memory usage to 2014 MB after concatenation, without modifying a and b.

Comment: You are still holding onto the original arrays.  After you add them to the list, clear them so they can be marked for garbage collection.  Although the memory may not be freed up right away as the GC will determine when to do it.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for, to be honest. After the concatenation, `a`, `b` and `concat` are independent - changing an element of `a` won't change `concat` or vice versa, for example. That means those elements have to be stored independently. Now you could keep an `IEnumerable<int>` which *didn't* have that property: `IEnumerable<int> concat = a.Concat(b);`. But that isn't a `List<int>`. If you *need* a `List<int>` and two arrays, you can't concatenate them in a sort of "referencing" way. If you can be more specific about the bigger picture, that would help.

Comment: I can't clear the original arrays. They are persistent. I just need to concatenate them, do some searching and then dispose the concatenated list.

Comment: So do you actually need it as a concatenated *list*, or just a *sequence*? You can search through a sequence easily. This is why the exact requirements are important.

Comment: Ah, `IEnumerable<int> concat = a.Concat(b);` works perfect. Good to know.

Comment: I was just curious how you can take arrays/array segments, and iterate over the new concatenated array. Didn't have to be a list.

Comment: It's not a concatenated *array* - that's the trick. It's just a sequence which "knows" that it's the concatenation of two arrays. All `IEnumerable<T>` needs to be able to do is return an iterator over the sequence. I'll add an answer now.

Comment: What I believe is if we use the pointer of int [] a we might achieve this less memory usage goal

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you need a `List<int>`, you can't do this. A `List<int>` always contains its data directly, so by the time you've got two arrays with (say) 100 elements, and a list which was created by concatenating those two, you've got 400 independent elements. You can't change that.

What you're looking for is a way of *not* creating an independent copy of the data. If you're just searching through it (as it sounds like in the comments) you can just use an `IEnumerable<int>` created with LINQ:

```
IEnumerable<int> concat = a.Concat(b);
```

If you needed something like an `IReadOnlyList<T>` or even an `IList<T>`, you could implement those interfaces yourself to create an adapter over multiple arrays - but you'd probably need to write that yourself. If you can stick with `IEnumerable<T>`, using LINQ will be a lot simpler.

Answer (score 5):

I can suggest you performing some optimizations:

1. Initialize a and b as `IEnumerable<int>` without call ToArray() method

   ```
   int size = 1000 * 1024 * 1024 / 4;
   IEnumerable<int> a = Enumerable.Range(0, size);
   IEnumerable<int> b = Enumerable.Range(0, size);
   ```
2. Initialize concat with a known capacity

   ```
   List<int> concat = new List<int>(size);
   ```

As the result I get the following output:

```
Initial memory size: 12 MB
Memory size after lists initialization: 13 MB
Memory size after lists concatenation: 1021 MB
```

If you just want to search something in concatenation you can do it like this without extra allocations:

```
IEnumerable<int> concat = a.Skip(500 * 1024 * 1024 / 4).Concat(b.Skip(500 * 1024 * 1024 / 4));
int search = concat.Count(i => i % 2 == 0);
Console.WriteLine($"Search result: {search}");
```

Answer (score 4):

> They are persistent. I just need to concatenate them, do some searching and then dispose the concatenated list

If you only need to do some searching, why do you need to concatenate in the first place? Search both arrays separately.

It could be the case that what you are searching might bridge both arrays. If that is the case, to make things easier and not pay the memory price, simply implement a wrapper that simulates the operation but doesn't actually perform it:

```
sealed class Concatenated<T>:
    IReadOnlyList<T>
{
    public static Concatenated<T> 
        Concatenate<T>(
            IReadOnlyList<T> first,
            IReadOnlyList<T> second)
        => new ConcatenatedArray<T>(first, second);

    private readonly IReadOnlyList<T>
       first, second;

    private Concatenated(
        IReadOnlyList<T> first,
        IReadOnlyList<T> second)
    {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public T this[int index] 
        => index < first.Length ? 
           first[index]: 
           second[index - first.Length];

    public int Count => first.Length + second.Length;

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var f in first)
            yield return f;

        foreach (var s in second)
            yield return s;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        => GetEnumerator();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Enumerable.Concat()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=netframework-4.7.2).  In the [source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L800), you can see that [`ConcatIterator`](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L806) first yields all items from `first` and then from `second`.  It does not copy the original `IEnumerables` (or arrays in this case), it uses references.
(*NOTE: for maximum speed and many small `IEnumerables` you should not do this, but for minimum memory consumption and a few large `IEnumerables` this works*)

Answer (score 3):

As InBetween mentions, you really shouldn't make a new list. I imagine his solution is what is the "best" solution.

In terms of answering your initial question, you're going to have issues due to how Garbage Collection works with .NET (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals).

In order to get around this, the best way will be to not use any of the built in containers to allow yourself to have full control of you memory usage without using any classes and allocating everything to the stack.

Here is some examples handling the allocations to have closer control over memory due to scoping:

```
    void MyFunc(IList<int> combinedList)
    {
      int[] a = new int[LARGE_COUNT]; // This will initialize to the default value of the type. (default)int == 0
      int[] b = new int[LARGE_COUNT];

      // Add whatever you want to combinedList. This will just add both.
      combinedList.AddRange(a);
      combinedList.AddRange(b);
    }
```

The section above will have a and b disposed of immediately due to them being stack allocations without using any classes. This will make proper use of the Garbage Collection difference in structs vs classes.

There is another way to do it a bit more heavy-handedly.

```
    List<int> concat = new List<int>();
    using (int[] a = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000 * 1024 * 1024 / 4).ToArray()){
        concat.AddRange(a.Skip(500 * 1024 * 1024 / 4));
    }
    using (int[] b = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000 * 1024 * 1024 / 4).ToArray()){
        concat.AddRange(b.Skip(500 * 1024 * 1024 / 4));
    }
    // Do a GC.Collect() if you really don't want to put this in it's own scope for some reason.
```

The GC.Collect() is a very aggressive way to get around learning the proper way .NET's garbage collection properly is setup to work.